# I can't log in with a new account

Tags: spore

I have recently installed Spore on a new computer. I used to have it on an older computer, but I forgot my account, so I made a new EA account and tried logging in. It keeps saying that I cannot connect to servers. I found out that EA was doing server maintenance for Spore back in August/September, so I initially thought this was the problem.

I found my old account and tried logging in, and it works, but I would rather use the new account I made. What can I do to successfully log in with my new account?

Comment: I have had the same issue, it could possibly be the GameSpy server shutdown that could have an effect on that, but not 100% sure. I have the same issue, and I've put my information in several times and sure it is right.

Comment: @CamouflagedCow Strange. Glad I'm not the only one though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't already have an Origin account, go to http://www.ea.com/ to make one. This will let you request help from the EA staff. 
Next, go to http://help.ea.com/. 
Click on the "Help with a Game" button. 
Search for Spore, scroll down to the bottom of the page and click "Contact Us".
Click your platform, click next and pick Billing/Purchasing from the topic list.

From there you can start a conversation from an EA support person. Talk to him/her about the problem and they'll correct any errors and fix the problems. After about 5 minutes, you should be able to make a Spore account in the game.

Comment: I have an EA account already, but I'll definitely try customer support. Thanks!